# Finding the third moment of a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given $X\sim Bin(n,p)$, I need to calculate this expression: $E[(X-E(X))^3]$ using the moment generating function.

So first of all, I used some algebra and got this simpler form:
$E(X^3)-3\mu E(X^2)+3\mu ^3-\mu ^3$, where $\mu =E(X)$.
now, finding the first and second moment wasn't too hard.
$M_X(k)=(pe^k+q)^n$, where $q=1-p$, is the moment generating function of X, so I found $M_X'(0)$ and $M_X''(0)$, who represents the first and second moment of X, respectively, now the problem is finding the third derivative $M_X'''(0)$.
The second derivative is awful enough, so finding the third involves some really ugly expression. No matter how much I tried, I just couldn't find this third derivative.

Here's $M_X''(k)$:

$M_X''(k)=npe^k(pe^k+q)^{n-1}+n(n-1)p^2e^{2k}(pe^k+q)^{n-2}$

Is there some elegant way to determine the third moment of X?

Comment: There is some symbol-smashing ugliness pretty much no matter what you do.

Comment: If you don't *have to* use the moment generating function, this problem is a lot easier using cumulants.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland, no, I have to use it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not need to evaluate the third derivative of the mgf, we need the third derivative **at** $0$. The mgf pf $X$ is $(1-p+pe^t)^n$, that is, $\left(1+p(e^t-1)\right)^n$. Expand $e^t-1$ (we just need the first three terma). So we are interested in the coefficient of $t^3$ in the expansion
$$\left(1+pt\left(1+\frac{t}{2!}+\frac{t^2}{3!}+\cdots\right)\right)^n.$$
Now use the Binomial Theorem.

The second term in the binomial expansion gives a contribution of $\binom{n}{1}p\frac{1}{3!}t^3$.

The third term gives a contribution of $\binom{n}{2}p^2 \frac{2}{2!}t^3$.

The fourth term gives a contribution of $\binom{n}{3}p^3 t^3$. Higher order terms make no contribution.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

$$
e^k n p \left(\left(e^k-1\right) p+1\right)^{n-3} \left(p^2 \left(e^{2 k}
   n^2+e^k (1-3 n)+1\right)+p \left(e^k (3 n-1)-2\right)+1\right)
$$